# VBA - My loop keeps excel Not Responding and eventually close

Tags: excel, vba, loops, oledbconnection

I'm trying to update three OLEDB connections and check if they are refreshing. If not, I want to loop until all are false, with a 5-second wait between loops. When I manually step through the code using F8, it works and eventually finishes. However, in normal execution, it freezes Excel after not responding for 10+ minutes.

Im lost here.

I have tried adding more waits or a msgbox between them, not working.

```
Sub update()
Dim a As Boolean, b As Boolean, c As Boolean
Dim ci As WorkbookConnection, ca As WorkbookConnection, av As WorkbookConnection

Set ci = ThisWorkbook.Connections("x")
Set ca = ThisWorkbook.Connections("y")
Set av = ThisWorkbook.Connections("z")

ci.Refresh
ca.Refresh
av.Refresh

a = ci.OLEDBConnection.Refreshing
b = ca.OLEDBConnection.Refreshing
c = av.OLEDBConnection.Refreshing


Do Until a = False And b = False And c = False

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))

a = ci.OLEDBConnection.Refreshing
b = ca.OLEDBConnection.Refreshing
c = av.OLEDBConnection.Refreshing

Loop

Calculate

Worksheets("AVANCE").PivotTables("TablaDinámica2").PivotCache.Refresh
End Sub
```

Comment: Try this delay subroutine instead of `Application.Wait` and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: It is probably worth adding [DoEvents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/doevents-function) to the empty loop so that the OS doesn't end up overflowing some critical events queue or other. It might also allow you to regain control if the thing still locks up. I find it annoying when Excel goes belly up like that.  It is quite useful for debugging code that latches up and goes unresponsive. Especially if it is some sort of race condition inside Excel so debugs OK but full speed falls over in a heap.